# (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false flooding my debugger

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

I am using tab interface and fragments to load different JSON clicking on each tab.

I am downloading images parsed from JSON, but the problem is that debugger is showing me tons of messages each time I touch screen

```
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: status 200
W/ImageDownloader: Error downloading image from null
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: status 200
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: status 200
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: status 200
W/ImageDownloader: Error downloading image from null
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
I/System.out: status 200
```

I understand this is system out that is written in class, but this is not supposed to be running so much times, it should download only once on first click not on each touch on screen

I am calling the JSON class in fragments **onViewCreated** and that class extends **AsyncTask**. I tried loading it from onPostExecute in this class and in different places in JSON class, but it looks like it is constantly trying to download images, but text is standing on place. It happens that images are changing in one imageView.

I am trying to download images initiating ImageDownloaderTask class from customlistadapter. This is being called too much times, should I move this download to somewhere else

```
new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.imageView).execute(newsItem.getImage());
```

This is part of my code which generates this in JSON

```
    private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try {
        URL uri = new URL(url);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();

        int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("status "+statusCode);

        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        if (inputStream != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            return bitmap;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        Log.w("ImageDownloader", "Error downloading image from " + url);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```